# Удаление маркера из кластера. Leaflet.markercluster

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Всем привет, как удалить маркеры из кластера? Проблема в том, что когда маркеры сгруппированы их нельзя удалить по условию, но как только эта группировка снимается, то сразу же появляется возможность на удаление.

[image: Перед удалением]
[image: После удаления]

Код добавление маркеров:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
map.addLayer(markers);

L.geoJSON(data, {
                pointToLayer: pointToLayer, 
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            })
            .on('click', markerOnClick)
            .addTo(markers);
```

Код удаления маркеров:

```
$.each(markers._map._layers, function (ml) {
    if (markers._map._layers[ml].feature) {
        if(markers._map._layers[ml].feature.properties.obj == 2 && markers._map._layers[ml].feature.properties.type == 1){                      
             markers.removeLayer(this);
        }            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение

```
 markers.eachLayer( function(layer){
   if(layer.feature.properties.obj == 2 && layer.feature.properties.type == 1) {  
                markers.removeLayer(layer);
   }
 });
```

Все потому что я искал каждый слой на карте, а маркеры, которые сгруппированы были заменены на слой кластера.